# Maximum size of .apk to upload on amazon app store

Tags: android

What Can be  Maximum size of .apk to upload on amazon app store. Actually my .apk file having images more than 50MB .so it's going approx 60 mb size of android app. Is it possible to upload 60mb file on amazon app store.

Is there any other solution like apk expansion on google play.Can we implement apk expanson to upload more than 50 mb apk file on amazon app store..

Answer (score 5):

While Amazon doesn't enforce a strict size limit on uploaded .apk files, it will only allow direct control panel uploads for files under 100 MB. Those over 100 MB will be directed to use an FTP server.

In general, Amazon advises to keep .apk files below 100 MB.

Source: [The Amazon Android Developer FAQ](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html)